# Android Pixel Perfect views in Android Device Monitor show nothing

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging, pixel-perfect

Using HierarchyViewer (in the Android Device Monitor) with an app running on an emulator works fine, but PixelPerfect shows nothing in any of the Pixel Perfect perspective views.  Has anyone else run into this?  There's little about Pixel Perfect on the web besides official docs, which have proved unhelpful so far.  I'm following the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#runhv), clicking on "Inspect Screenshot" as prescribed.